# Why is my question not appearing in the unanswered questions list?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, unanswered-questions

I recently asked this question on Physics SE:

[Is there an underlying physical reason why the Coriolis force is similar to the magnetic component of the Lorentz force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/242499/is-there-an-underlying-physical-reason-why-the-coriolis-force-is-similar-to-the)

Although I didn't accept any of the answers, I can't find it in the unanswered questions list. Is there a possible reason why this is happening?

(I should clarify I'm totally new here, so please excuse me if I'm missing something).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A question is considered answered if one of the posted answers has a score of >1, which is the case here for your question.

Comment: Yes. The site-wide `Unanswered` questions list makes it clear that these are "$N$ questions with no upvoted or accepted answers" (top right corner). (There is an ambiguity there as 'upvoted' and 'positive-score' are different and have different consequences (e.g. with question deletion) but [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18870/) suggests the criterion is positive score.) Tag-specific lists (such as [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics)) appear to have the same behaviour.